# How to programmatically change screen brightness thru Intel graphics in C#

Tags: c#, c++, graphics, intel

I tried using `WmiMonitorBrightness` class of the Windows Management Instrumentation but my system does not support it. I also tried changing gamma thru `SetDeviceGammaRamp` API function but, meh..

Then I checked the power option in windows 10 if it has the brightness control slider and it has none which I suspect is connected to why `WmiMonitorBrightness` does not work on my OS.

Finally, I found out that I can manually change the brightness thru the color setting of Intel HD Graphics control panel. Now I want to ask how to change screen brightness using code like how Intel does it. I am running my OS in an Intel Pentium N4200 microprocessor @ 1.10Ghz clockspeed and I use a touchscreen UI, if that matters.

edit: I found out that Intel HD Graphics control panel does not change the backlight brightness of panel but just the color brightness.

Comment: Are you talking about laptop backlight brightness, or only collor-correction tweaks like gamma that would work even with a dumb external monitor?

Comment: This is for robot application running on a microprocessor. It has a touchscreen UI running windows 10. I want to access the hardware's backlight brightness if possible.

Comment: You should edit that into the question, along with more detail on what hardware you care about this working on.  Embedded Intel systems don't use the same GPUs as their desktop/laptop chips, and have different drivers.  That might or might not matter, depending on whether that `SetMonitorBrightness` D3D function suggested in an answer works for you.  (I don't even use Windows, so *I* don't know the answer, sorry.)

Comment: I meant to include details on *what* microprocessor.  My Skylake i7-6700k desktop is a microprocessor; the word is [basically a synonym for modern CPU](http://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/), but I think that's not what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

> SetMonitorBrightness

[Here's the Microsoft link for it.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/highlevelmonitorconfigurationapi/nf-highlevelmonitorconfigurationapi-setmonitorbrightness)

Comment: My system can use this function. Do you know any implementation of this?

Comment: I’ll dig around and see if I can find an implementation for you.

Comment: To answer my own question, I was able to find this [link](https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/396275-controlling-screen-brightness-using-ddcci/).