# How to change color temperature for only a part of the screen in Windows 10 or later

Tags: windows, winapi, screen

I'm using a blue light cut application called [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/), but since the forum has been stopped for a long time and the update has stopped in 2021, I'm wondering if I can make an improved version by myself.
f.lux has a function that turns off the blue light cutoff function(color temperature setting to be precise) when a specified application is launched, but when an app(e.g. image editing software or comic book viewer) is opened, the function is turned off not only for that application but for the entire screen, causing a glaring problem. I would like to cut the blue light only a part of the screen(or turn off the blue light cut only when opening YouTube or [pixiv](https://www.pixiv.net/en/) in the browser, etc.).

The following page seems there is a way to change the color temperature of the entire screen, but not just a part of it. Also, the [SetDeviceGammaRamp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setdevicegammaramp) that is introduced seems to be deprecated now.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65641362/3809427

Comment: As [SetDeviceGammaRamp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setdevicegammaramp) said, *For blue light filtering, Windows now provides built-in support called [Night Light](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4027563/windows-10-set-your-display-for-night-time). Microsoft recommends directing users to this feature.*

Comment: I want to filter blue light for "only a part of the screen".

Comment: You can use [Window.Compositor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.composition.compositor?view=windows-app-sdk-1.3) to change windows' temperature. For example [PhotoEditor](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK-Samples/blob/101bbd12b6b6cd681ad841174fb36f4c3f430e7e/Samples/PhotoEditor/cs-winui/LoadedImageBrush.cs#L210).

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT Sorry for the additional question, but the sample code seems to change the temperature only for image files. Perhaps [CompositionBackdropBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.composition.compositionbackdropbrush?view=windows-app-sdk-1.3) might solve my question, but, I don't know how to get the `graphicsDevice` in the code of [SpriteVisual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.composition.spritevisual?view=windows-app-sdk-1.3).

Comment: [The Compositor instance is bound to windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.window.compositor?view=winrt-22621). You can check the more suitable sample [ScreenCaptureforHWND](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows.UI.Composition-Win32-Samples/blob/ee50e2ea137dcef7b82ba504eff7435e5ebf5294/cpp/ScreenCaptureforHWND/ScreenCaptureforHWND/composition.interop.h#L6).

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT Sorry for question again, ( I may be mistaken because I have no knowledge of C/C++) but isn't it for a window created by one's program? Is it for the whole screen including external apps?